# Как сравнить две текстовые переменные на php?

Tags: php

Есть две переменные в одной из них значение поля "пароль" в другой "повторите пароль"... И как их можно сравнить на совпадение?

Answer (score 5):

Сравнивать нужно либо:

```
strcmp(str1,str2)
```

либо

```
if( $str1 === $str2 ) ... //(это не опечатка, а 3 равно)
```

ибо

```
var_dump("044" == "44");
//выведет bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 = "Hello";
$string2 = "World";
if ($string1 == $string2){ print "Переменные равны"; }    
else { print "Переменные не равны"; }
```

Comment: попробуйте сравнить таким способом `"0e42"` и `"0e123"`, например

Answer (score 0):

да хоть так:

```
if ($password == $confirm)
```

или так:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Answer (score 0):

```
strcmp(str1,str2)
```

Подробнее: http://php.su/functions/?strcmp